# AWS CDK and two EKS clusters sharing the same IAM Roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

This is probably not unique to these exact components, but this is where I have encountered this problem:

I am standing up multiple EKS clusters with CDK and they all need to be able to assume certain IAM roles with RBAC to do AWS-y things. For instance:

```
        var AllowExternalDNSUpdatesRole = new Role(
            this,
            "AllowExternalDNSUpdatesRole",
            new RoleProps
            {
                Description = "Route53 External DNS Role",
                InlinePolicies = new Dictionary<string, PolicyDocument>
                {
                    ["AllowExternalDNSUpdates"] = externalDnsPolicy
                },
                RoleName = "AllowExternalDNSUpdatesRole",
                AssumedBy = new FederatedPrincipal(Cluster.OpenIdConnectProvider.OpenIdConnectProviderArn, new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    ["StringLike"] = ExternalDnsCondition,
                }, "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"),
            }
        );
```

I'm giving it a RoleName so I can reference it in a sane way in the Kubernetes yaml files. At the time I'm creating the role, I need to be able to create a FederatedPrincipal referring to the Cluster's OIDC provider so I can drop it in `AssumedBy`. I can't create the same named role when I stand up the second or nth cluster. It bombs spectacularly.

Ideally I would create these kinds of roles in their own IAM-only stack, and then attach the FederatedPrincipal to the created roles at EKS Cluster creation time. I have tried to figure out how to do that. When these clusters get built up and torn down they would just add and remove themselves from the AssumedBy part of the role. I would love a clue to help me figure that out.

Beyond that the only other thing I can think of to do is to create roles-per-cluster and then have to modify the YAML to refer to the uniquely-named generated roles. That is less than ideal. I'm trying to avoid having to maintain per-cluster yaml files for Kubernetes.

I'm game for other strategies too....

Comment: I would recommend seperate roles for each cluster. Your external-dns pods will already need diverging configurations (`--txt-owner-id` is needed to run two against the same zone safely). Does your method of deploying manifests not have way to inject the IAM role annotation?

Comment: @jordanm We're just trying to keep the number of moving parts to a minimum. There's no tooling around the yaml files. Nothing blipped at me regarding the external-dns needing to be different across pods. The Route53 domain in question isn't managed by CDK. I suppose if it were the --txt-owner-id would be dynamic